# Do Europe committees care about my community service for GRE learners?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, united-kingdom, gre, europe

I have finished applying into US schools, and now I turn to other countries. Since I don't think that there is much different between US and Europe (more specifically, UK) in the requirements in the SOP, I plan to just simply reuse it (of course this time I'll use the British spelling checker).

However, in my SOP apply to the US schools, I have a paragraph describes my contribution to GRE learners. While it may help when it serves US committees, I wonder if it would help in Europe ones. Apparently it's because GRE score is not required in Europe. It can be possibly that they don't even know what GRE is for.

**Q**: So, is it worth the space to mention about the contribution for GRE learners?

My draft is as follows:

> I also have contributed to GRE learners community with a refined Anki deck. One powerful flashcard program that is very helpful to learn GRE vocabulary is Anki. Although I have managed to learn a lot of words from existing shared decks, these decks were poorly designed, hindering the effectiveness in memorizing words. Seeing the need to have a well-designed deck, not only for me, but also for the community; I decided to dedicate one month just to create one so that the spaced repetition method could achieve its highest potential. Once complete I posted it on my website. The result was incredible. Every month approximately a hundred visitors download it from my site. Within a couple months this popularity has pushed my site to the front page of Google, and the good news is that I haven't forgotten a single word since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: So, is it worth the space to mention about the contribution for GRE learners?

I see no difference in this matter between US and European schools. If you felt it was worth the space for the US, keep it in. Your "community service" was to create a Anki deck for a common test. Whether the school you are applying to is using this specific test or not does not change the value of your contribution.

If you are worried that the admission committee reading your application does not know the GRE, you can always add a short sidenote that explains what it is.

Comment: How likely that they don't know about the test?

Comment: @Ooker That is impossible to answer. Why not just add a single-line summary if you are afraid of them not knowing about it?

Comment: Sure I will do that. I just ask to know